# Quickblox Chat , Android

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I am using Quickblox XMPP server, i am using the sample provided by Quickblox. It works totally fine on my (San Francisco 2 2.3.5) & HTC Explorer (2.3.5) but it won't run on my Samsung Note 3 (4.1.2) and Samsung galaxy tab t210.
Is there any android version issue? whose knowledge i am missing?

Project can be downloaded from here
    https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/archive/master.zip

The guide i follow is 
    http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Won't run how? More information would be required to give any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: The application starts, and after 2 3 sec lag. black screen appears showing " application stopped working unfortunately".

Comment: By more information I am saying post your logcat. Then post the code, then run it in a debugger and see where it fails and post what you are seeing.

Answer (score -1):

i have read your question.if you want a chat app than i have better solution for you.

http://goo.gl/rgTpRz